# How to change layout font of android studio software

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, fonts, truetype

[image]

so i change font style of android studio (Not font of code or font of android simulator)

Comment: try downloading studio form this link . https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Press **Ctrl+Alt+S**: This will take you to **Settings**.
[image]

Inside very first option **Appearance & Behavior > Appearance**, there is a check-box to **Override default fonts by(not recommended),** you can change fonts from there or disable that option.

Don't forget to click **Apply**.